# is it available to pay for my multiple inputs at one time?

Tags: bitcoind

I have a Bitcoin wallet and there is a large number of spendable addresses.
if i make a transaction and there is a multiple inputs which is belonged to me(my wallet),  is it possible to pay a fee by the single address? (Is it possible to pay fees for my other bitcoin addresses?)

Answer (score 1):

Within a bitcoin transaction, there is no specification for *'which address (input) is paying the fee'*.

The fee is simply calculated by subtracting the sum of all outputs, from the sum of all inputs. The inputs are consumed entirely, and the newly formed UTXOs specify the exact amount paying each address. Whatever is left over is the fee that miners can claim.